# MySQL View of 2 tables with some identical columns

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to make a SQL view of 2 different tables with some identical fields and some unique fields.

With both tables having their userId as their PK

```
Table Male
+--------+-------+-------+---------+------------+
| UserId | Fname | Lname | Contact | DOB        |                                                                                                  
+--------+-------+-------+---------+------------+ 
| abcd1  | Jack  | Smith | 1234555 | 12/12/1954 |                                                                                                                
| abcd2  | John  | White | 1234333 | 01/09/1960 |                                                                                                                 
| abcd3  | David | King  | 1234444 | 23/01/1973 |                                                                                                                 
+--------+-------+-------+---------+------------+
Table Female
+--------+-------+-------+-------------------+------------+
| UserId | Fname | Lname | Email             | Age        |                                                                                                  
+--------+-------+-------+-------------------+------------+ 
| abcd1  | Sally | Smith | sally@example.com | 40         |                                                                                                                
| abcd2  | Lily  | White | lily@example.com  | 35         |                                                                                                                 
| abcd3  | Susan | King  | susan@example.com | 55         |                                                                                                                 
+--------+-------+-------+-------------------+------------+
```

I would like to create a view of this 2 tables that returns my query with these 2 criteria:

```
SELECT * FROM view_members WHERE UserId = 'abcd1';
+--------------+-------+-------+---------+------------+-------------------+------------+
| UserId       | Fname | Lname | Contact | DOB        | Email             | Age        |                                                                                                  
+--------------+-------+-------+---------+------------+-------------------+------------+ 
| male_abcd1   | Jack  | Smith | 1234555 | 12/12/1954 | NULL              | NULL       |
+--------------+-------+-------+---------+------------+-------------------+------------+
| female_abcd1 | Sally | Smith | NULL    | NULL       | sally@example.com | 40         |
+--------------+-------+-------+---------+------------+-------------------+------------+
```

The primary key of UserId from the two tables will remain the identifier, and the value returned will be appended with the respective table names. As for values that are unique to each table will return null for results drawn from the other tables.

Are there any possible solution for this? Any logic to be added into my Create View statement to make this work?

Comment: It is not clear what you want your query to return in terms of inputs. PS [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Use a union approach:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('male_', UserId) AS UserId, Fname, Lname, Contact, DOB, NULL AS Email, Age
FROM Male
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('female_', UserId), Fname, Lname, NULL, NULL, Email, Age
FROM Female;
```

Note that we are using `NULL` placeholders in the select statements when a particular column not exist within a certain table.  For example, in the first select we use `NULL` as a placeholder for the email, because the `Male` table does not have this columnn.

Comment: Would this be able to achieve the male_userId and female_userId?

Comment: @whatanoob Check my updated answer.  We can try concatenating the correct `male_` or `female_` prefix to the `UserId` using the source table.

Comment: This will not allow you to query for UserId = 'abcd' and get both gender rows, as you requested.  As I noted, it's not possible, even though you can create a computed column in the view.

Comment: @gview I disagree with what you have noted, and it is perfectly possible to add a filter on both halves of the query for `UserId = 'abcd1'`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am referring to what was requested.  What was requested was a transformation in the view, of the UserId to the format of either 'female_abcd1' or 'male_abcd1', yet also to be able to query only for 'abcd1'.  Yes, one can concat male or female to the front of the column, although to what end, I'm not sure.  But once you create that view, SELECT * from the_view WHERE UserId = 'abcd1' will not return any rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a view where you redefine the values of a column only after querying it.  You can define the view as a union.  Just hardwire a gender value.

```
CREATE VIEW your_view AS
SELECT UserId, Gender AS 'Male', Fname, Lname, Contact, DOB, NULL AS Email, Age FROM Male
UNION ALL
SELECT UserId, Gender AS 'Female', Fname, Lname, NULL, NULL, Email, Age FROM Female;
```

Now you can get both male and female rows from a SELECT statement, or get just the female or male version by adding Gender criteria.

Assume a male and female row with the same ID as in your example:

```
SELECT * FROM your_view WHERE UserId = 'abcd1' AND Gender = 'Male'
```

Leave out Gender if you desire both male and female rows.

Comment: How will I use the hardwire gender value?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you want.  For example, if you want UserId 33, but you want the Male, then you can select from the view with `SELECT * FROM viewname WHERE UserId = 33 AND Gender = 'Male'`.  Ordinary SELECT * ... will display the Gender column.